# how to pass arguments between pythons scripts in MAYA?

Tags: python-2.7, arguments, maya

I'm new in python and i'm trying to pass arguments between different scripts but they only update one way:
i'm calling the first script in maya with a shelf like this:

```
try:
        myPM.close()
except:pass
import sys
sys.path.append("C:/Users/manue/Desktop/test")
import UiMayaTest as SBIRP
reload(SBIRP)
myPM = SBIRP.createUI()
```

this called script 'UiMayaTest.py' is a simple window with an intField entry and a button:

```
import sys
import maya.cmds as cmds
from functools import partial

def buttonPressed(episode, *args):
    passValue(episode, *args)
    print '============== buttonPressed ================'
    print 'EpisodeName ', EpisodeName

    Var = ''
    import UiMayaTestFunction
    Var = UiMayaTestFunction.FindVarFunc(EpisodeName,Var)
    print 'Var : ',Var

def createUI(): 
    myWindow = "SomeWindow"
    if cmds.window(myWindow,ex=True):
        cmds.deleteUI(myWindow)
    cmds.window(myWindow)
    cmds.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=True )
    cmds.text( label='Episode:  ', align='left' )
    episode = cmds.intField( "Episode", minValue = 100, maxValue = 1000, value =100)
    cmds.button(l="Open Last LIT scene", w=150, h=30, command=partial(buttonPressed,episode))
    cmds.setParent("..")
    cmds.showWindow()

def passValue(episode, *args):
    global EpisodeName
    EpisodeName = `cmds.intField( episode, query = True, value = True)`
```

and the script called by it is called 'UiMayaTestFunction.py' and just return a variable called Var:

```
def FindVarFunc(EpisodeName, Var):
    print '============== FindVarFunc ================'
    print 'EpisodeName:' , EpisodeName 
    Var = 'Hello world'
    print 'Var: ',Var
    return Var
```

the variable 'EpisodeName' from UiMayaTest to UiMayaTestFunction is well updated each time i press the button,
but if i change the variable 'Var' in UiMayaTestFunction , it doesn't update it, i've got always the same print or 'Var'...
Thanks by advance for any help...

Answer (score 1):

Well.... it seems that the script does exactly do what it is supposed to do. What result for your Var variable do you expect?
Let's see.. if the button is pressed, the buttonPressed() function is called. There the variable 'Var' is initialized with an empty string ''. Then teh FindVarFunc() is called with the argument Var, what is still an empty string. In the FindVarFunc() the Variable 'Var' is printed and returnde, what is still.... well you guess it: an empty string. And finally the result of the function is assigned to the variable 'Var', and the result is... an empty string which is printed. It could help to assign 'Var' something else but an empty string to see if it works better.

Comment: thanks but the variable 'Var'  in the  second scipt UiMayaTestFunction.py  ligne: Var = 'Hello world' return well the print Hello world in UiMayaTest.py... but if i change Var = 'sunday' in UiMayaTestFunction... the UiMayaTest return me always  'Hello world', like if i doesn't refresh or update...

Comment: Any change in an external module will not be updated until you reload the module. An import alone will only load the module once. So if you change something in the UiMayaTestFunction.py you will have to do a reload(UiMayaTestFunction) before calling the FindVarFunc()

Comment: Ohhh thanks a lot Haggi! that's working perfect :)))

Comment: Do you think it's a good method or this is very dirty python?

Comment: Your code can be a bit more 'pythonic' what means you can use a class for your UI code where you can encapsulate all necessary data and procedures. And maybe separating modules in testing pase is a source of problems. I'd first try to keep everything in one module and if it makes sense, then later extract another module like your UiMayaTestFunction.py.